# Why can NS_ENUM be defined in that way

Tags: objective-c

Am new to Objetive-C and today i encountered NS_ENUM marco which can be used like:

```
typedef NS_ENUM(Type, MyType) {
 Foo,
 Bar
};
```

The usage is a little bit weird what why `typedof` must be used here, so i checked the source code of NS_ENUM:

```
#if (__cplusplus && __cplusplus >= 201103L &&
        (__has_extension(cxx_strong_enums) ||
         __has_feature(objc_fixed_enum))
    ) ||
    (!__cplusplus && __has_feature(objc_fixed_enum))
    #define NS_ENUM(_type, _name)
            enum _name : _type _name; enum _name : _type
    #if (__cplusplus)
        #define NS_OPTIONS(_type, _name)
                _type _name; enum : _type
    #else
        #define NS_OPTIONS(_type, _name)
                enum _name : _type _name; enum _name : _type
    #endif
#else
    #define NS_ENUM(_type, _name) _type _name; enum
    #define NS_OPTIONS(_type, _name) _type _name; enum
#endif
```

The way NS_ENUM is being defined makes me more confused, because i don't understand the syntax here, could anyone explain the definition from the syntactic perspective in details? Thanks.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_preprocessor

Comment: http://clang.llvm.org/docs/LanguageExtensions.html#enumerations-with-a-fixed-underlying-type

Comment: http://www.apeth.com/iOSBook/ch01.html#SBnewenum

Comment: @Merlevede i know macro preprocessor, what am asking is the syntax :NS_ENUM(_type, _name)
            enum _name : _type _name; enum _name : _type

Comment: @Bryan Chen see above

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's a simple string substitution mechanism. This

```
#define NS_ENUM(_type, _name)
        enum _name : _type _name; enum _name : _type
```

means that this

```
typedef NS_ENUM(int, myEnumType)
```

will be replaced by this

```
enum myEnumType : int myEnumType;
enum myEnumType : int
```

From [this source](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2dzy4k6e%28v=VS.100%29.aspx) you can see that the **enum** syntax is:

```
enum [tag] [: type] {enum-list} [declarator];   // for definition of enumerated type
enum tag declarator;   // for declaration of variable of type tag
```

Comment: You are missing the `typdef` in the replacement. The `typdef` is not replaced, the first line is `typdef enum myEnumType : int myEnumType;` after replacement and is required to be able to use `myEnumType` instead of `enum myEnumType`.

Answer (score 2):

See: [NS_ENUM & NS_OPTIONS](http://nshipster.com/ns_enum-ns_options/) for complete information and usage.

From NSHipster: "Introduced in Foundation with iOS 6 / Mac OS X 10.8, the NS_ENUM and NS_OPTIONS macros are the new, preferred way to declare enum types."